# Error in Saving rpt file within WPF C# Application

Tags: c#, wpf

i have an Folder named as "NewFolder1" with my application.I want to save the rpt file in that folder,but my code do nothing.
Thanks in advance
code:

[here is the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcxPM.png)

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument report = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();

        report.Load("CrystalReport5.rpt");

       report.SaveAs( System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("\\NewFolder1\\poiu.rpt"));

        Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
    }
```

Comment: try `report.SaveAs( System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "NewFolder1\\poiu.rpt"));`

Comment: Try `Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("\\NewFolder1\\poiu.rpt"));` and see what path you get in the console output. Is this what you want?

Comment: thank u for your answers